# Reading information from a Yaml file which is not located in the src folder in java

Tags: java, jar, yaml

here is my problem. I'm trying to read information in a yaml file, which is located in a jar file, located in a external folder.

The things is, i can't find any information on that on the internet. What i tought to do was making a function like :

```
public void getPermission(String directory){
  Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
  ** some code that allow me to push what's under Permissions in the yaml file, in an ArrayList**
 }
```

Here is a sample of my yaml file

```
Permissions:
 creditcard.user:
  description: Player Commands for DebitCard
  default:true
 creditcard.register
  description: register DebitCard
  default op
```

Thanks and have a good day !

-Nic

Comment: And have you investigated Java's classes that let you read information from JAR files?

Comment: "which is located in a jar file, located in a external folder" How can it be both?  What do you mean "external"?

Comment: Well for exemple, the jar file are placed into " C:\User\Desktop\Plugins" and i need to read the permission that would be stocked into "C:\User\Desktop\Plugins\plugins.jar\plugin.yml"